# Cannot reset readonly input text

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input text which i use to show results of computation:

`<input type="text" id="total" readonly/>`

The total gets populated inside a function on a js file as follows:

```
//Inside a .js file
function calculate(){
    document.getElementById("total").setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("amount").value * 45);
}
```

and i also have a reset button which resets the form, but it doesn't reset the readonly input text:

`<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>`

I have tried changing the reset to button and wrote my function to disable readonly, reset then enable readonly but it doesn't work as well:

`<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetForm(this.form.name);"/>`

```
//Inside .js file
function resetForm(formName){
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = false;
    document.forms[formName].reset();
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = true;
}
```

Does anyone know a workaround of this case? I am new to javascript and i am doing this as a learning purpose only.

Heres the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="allJsCodesHere.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <strong>CDs Purchase Order</strong></h1>
        <form name="ex2Form" action = "">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Number of CDs ordered:
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="amount" value="0"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        At the rate of AED 45 for each CD
                    </td>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Total Order:
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="total" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetForm(this.form.name);"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </form>
        <footer>
            <p>Created by Mir Adnan Siraj</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The calculate function:

```
function calculate(){
    document.getElementById("total").setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("amount").value * 45);
}
```

Comment: document.forms[formName] console.log this and see output

Comment: Can't you just set the input value to '' on clicking reset?

Comment: instead of `document.getElementById("total").readonly = false;` try `document.getElementById("total").removeAttribute('readonly');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Document.forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) returns a collection of all of the forms within a particular page. Writing `document.forms["myForm"]` will return the form with the name `"myForm"` from that collection. So what you need to do is this. Say for example your form name is myForm with an id of myForm.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input id="email" name="email" value="some@email.com" />
</form>
```

Now to access this form, you have to do this.

```
document.forms["myForm"].reset()
```

This will reset your form successfully. So to be clearly, you are doing everything perfectly just console.log and check the parameter passed. You dont need to reset all the fields manually by assigning them empty string. Thats wrong!

```
//Inside .js file
function resetForm(formName){ //==========> this needs to return the form name. console.log and check if its returning the formname
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = false;
    document.forms['formName'].reset();
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = true;
}
```

Comment: It does show my forms name on console without any error but still doesn't reset the readonly text

Comment: As a comment or you want me to post it as an answer because its about 50 lines?

Comment: then maybe its the IDE I am using, I am using brackets wbu? Btw did you try resetting then trying in some values and checking if it shows total?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your inputs inside a form you'll need to prevent the default behavior of a form, which is to send a request to any URL you might pass and refresh the page, which you don't want, I suppose. To do this, if you are triggering your reset function by attaching a listener to the submit event on a form, you'll need to use the event and call the `.preventDefault` method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Your function:

```
//Inside .js file
function resetForm(formName){
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = false;
    document.forms[formName].reset();
    document.getElementById("total").readonly = true;
}
```

Try changing it to this:

```
//Inside .js file
    function resetForm(){
        const form = document.getElementById("formName");
        const totalInput = document.getElementById("total");

        form.reset() // Resetting form 
        totalInput.readOnly = false; // Making readonly false so input is editable
    }
```

Here's a codesandbox where you can try this out

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-frost-4pnbz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does clear the readonly text but after that the text area doesn't work anymore until i refresh the page. Any way to fix that?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work you mean it's still readonly right?